# How to view all users on a database - JDBC Struts

Tags: java, jsp, jdbc, struts2

On my database table I have 6 rows of users.

I want to display all the users in the database.

When I run my code I get the value for the 6th row 6 times.

**Java**

```
public String allMembers() throws SQLException {
List<String> members = new ArrayList<String>();
    try{ 
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Web", "root", "root");
        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
         ResultSet res = statement.executeQuery("select * from Users");
        while (res.next()){
            setUserName(res.getString("userName"));
            userName = userName.trim();
            members.add(userName);
        }
        connection.close();
    }catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "SUCCESS";
}
```

JSP

```
 <td>
     <b>Example of Iterator Tag</b><br/>
     <s:iterator value="members" status="ctr">
     <s:property value="userName"/> 
      </s:iterator>
      <br/><br/>
    </td>
```

How can I fix this and get it to display all users.

**String userName**

```
private String userName;
public String getUserName() {
    return userName;
}

public void setUserName(String userName) {
    this.userName = userName;
}
```

Comment: Share code for setUserName please... something strange there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In your action class**

```
List<String> members = new ArrayList<String>();

public List<String> getMembers() {
        return members;
    }

    public void setMembers(List<String> members) {
        this.members = members;
    }
```

**In your jsp**

```
<s:iterator value="members" status="memberStatus">
  <tr> 
      <td><s:property/></td>

  </tr>
</s:iterator>
```

Comment: Thanks I got it to display them correctly now :) I've been trying to fix it for hours

Comment: Glad to know.. :) If you need more information follow this [link](https://struts.apache.org/docs/iterator.html)

Comment: Do you know how i can control how its displayed because i have images to display with each username ?

Comment: @Judd if Madushan Perera's answer fixed your problem, you should upvote and accept it

Comment: Just did that, Thanks I'm still new here.

Answer (score 0):

You do

```
setUserName(res.getString("userName"));
```

Which does unknown things. But then you continue...

```
        userName = userName.trim();
        members.add(userName);
```

Where does userName come from? Where is it set to what?